# can't execute commands at if

Tags: c

I have a problem with a program. When I debug it the `fd2 is < 0` and does not get that if. Check it out.

```
printf("Enter file name: ");
scanf(" %s", file_name);

 printf("Enter file name2: ");
 scanf(" %s", file_name2);

fd=open(file_name, O_RDWR, S_IRWXU);
fd2=open(file_name2, O_RDWR, S_IRWXU);

if(fd2<0){
    printf("Error opening file!\n%s\n", strerror(errno));
    return(-1);
}

if(fd<0){
    printf("Error opening file!\n%s\n", strerror(errno));
    return(-1);
}
```

[image]

Comment: No need for C# tag. I removed it.

Comment: And when you ran it in a debugger what did you learn?

Comment: file doesn't exist? maybe add `| O_CREAT` to the flags?

Comment: that my program does not get in that if(fd2<0) and continues to run until i crashes at a write as i have the fd2 as argument

Comment: i have already created 2 files at my catalog

Comment: Put your error/debugging as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine. Check the return value of `open()` correctly, if `open()` failed means either permission issue.

```
fd=open(file_name, O_RDWR, S_IRWXU);
```

`fd` is a file descriptor and you can check it using

```
ls -l /proc/pid/fd
ls -l /proc/pid/fd   /* check here what value its prints */
```

And

```
#include<errno.h>
int main() {

            char file_name[50],file_name2[50];
            printf("Enter file name: ");
            scanf(" %s", file_name);
            int fd,fd2;
            printf("Enter file name2: ");
            scanf(" %s", file_name2);

            fd=open(file_name, O_RDWR, S_IRWXU);
            if(fd < 0) {
                    printf("Error opening file!\n%d\n", strerror(errno));/* use  %d instead of %s */
                    return 0; /* upon failure open() returns 0 not -1 */
            }
            fd2=open(file_name2, O_RDWR, S_IRWXU);
            if(fd2 < 0) {
                    printf("Error opening file!\n%d\n", strerror(errno));
                    return 0;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Printing the error strings from `strerror()` with `%d` is unlikely to lead to useful information.

Answer (score -1):

`fd`, meaning "file descriptor", is a value returned by `open` that you can use for your subsequent accesses to your file with functions like `read` and `write`.

It can be *any* integer value, except `-1`, which is used to tell you there was an error opening the file.

`fd<0` but not `-1` is thus fine.

Comment: thanks, i read at man page that open returns -1 if error occurred,  so i thought everything bellow 0 would be a open error

Comment: Successfully opened file descriptors are non-negative. The only error value is `-1`; any other negative value is an invalid file descriptor (generates `EBADF` if used with a function call that requires a valid file descriptor).  See POSIX [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) — _Upon successful completion, these functions shall open the file and return a non-negative integer representing the file descriptor. Otherwise, these functions shall return -1 and set `errno` to indicate the error. If -1 is returned, no files shall be created or modified._

Comment: Consequently, I disagree with the assertion that "`fd < 0` but not `-1` is thus fine".

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, from VC documentation: "_returns a file descriptor for the opened file. A return value of -1 indicates an error, in which case errno is set_". So at best this is compiler dependent and the compiler's documentation must be checked.